# Haskell Org Babel Eval Not Working Results Output

Tags: haskell, org-babel

Running babel source block evaluation on the following code results in an empty generated Results block:

```
#+NAME test
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell :tangle test.hs :results output
  let sayHello x = putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ x ++ "!")
  sayHello "Dave"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

When typing the above lines directly in ghci, however, I get the 
results as expected:

```
Prelude> let sayHello x = putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ x ++ "!")
Prelude> sayHello "Dave"
Hello, Dave!
Prelude>
```

According to the org babel documentation, the ":results output" option captures everything written from STDOUT so the evaluation of the code block should give the expected results. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update (11/14/16 10:05 am):**

When I use the following org code I get a partial result but not the expected results:

```
#+NAME test
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell :tangle test.hs :results output replace 
  let sayHello x = putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ x ++ "!")
  sayHello "Dave"
  sayHello "Steve"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: Hello, Dave!
```

When I look at the haskell buffer after babel eval, I see the following:

```
Prelude> let sayHello x = putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ x ++ "!")
sayHello "Dave"
sayHello "Steve"
"org-babel-haskell-eoe"
Prelude> Hello, Dave!
Prelude> Hello, Steve!
Prelude> "org-babel-haskell-eoe"
Prelude>
```